# Rails client_side_validations not working with non-db model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation, client-side-validation

I am trying to add lient side validations based on the model to my contact form by this gem: [client side validations](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations)
I followed the tutorial on their page. I added the gem, bundled it, run the generator, and copied the assets.

Unfortunately it doesn't work. When I submit the form, it doesn't validate. Just go to the create controller and render response about an error.

Model:

```
 class Message

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :phone, :body

  validates :name, :email, :phone, :body, :presence => true
  validates :email, :format => { :with => %r{.+@.+\..+} }, :allow_blank => true

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

end
```

HTML:

```
    <h2>Formularz kontaktowy</h2>
    <%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path, 
    :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}, 
    :validate => true do |f| %>

        <% if flash %>
          <% flash.each do |key,value| %>
            <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}") %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>


    <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Imie Nazwisko / Nazwa firmy" %>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">         
      <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Adres e-mail" %>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">    
    <%= f.text_field :phone, :placeholder => "Telefon kontaktowy" %>        
</div>

<div class="control-group">   
   <%= f.text_area :body, :placeholder => "Treść zapytania", :rows => 5 %>      
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <%= f.submit "Wyślij", :class => "btn" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])

    if @message.valid?
      NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: which version of rails are you using?

Comment: Version of rails: 3.2.14